# Get input value for apex controller in Lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to get the input text value from a search bar in my app to my apex controller to be used in a SOSL query.

Easy in VF. Something like:

cmp

```
<ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!searchVar}"
           placeholder="Search"/>
```

apex

```
public String searchVar {get;set;}
```

But when I debug the searchVar variable is null. 
I am guessing a helper needs to get it over for mef, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: I'm not really an expert but this might be somewhere to start. I don't think the searchvar in the inputtext should have the v. at the beginning. It should be "searchVar"

Comment: Sorry I will make the edit. That is how I tried it at first. Same issue, null value in apex debug logs. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AllenMann you need to pass the value to the controller's `AuraEnabled` method as parameter using `setParams()`.It is discussed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lightning_components/lightning_components_apex)

Comment: Please show your client controller code. Unlike Visualforce, in Lightning the values in the expression language are not auto bound to apex variables since lightning is a client side framework. You need to write code in your client controller to pass component values to your server side apex classes or to retrieve values from those classes.  This is covered in the developer guide.

Comment: ({
    getArts: function(cmp){
        
        var action = cmp.get("c.getArticlesList");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            
            action.setParams({ searchVar : cmp.get("v.searchVar") });
            var state = response.getState();
            
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.articles", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            
        });
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [unit here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lightning_components/lightning_components_apex) in Trailhead that shows a simple example, code below:

---

Apex controller:

```
public with sharing class SimpleServerSideController {

    //Use @AuraEnabled to enable client- and server-side access to the method
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String serverEcho(String firstName) {
        return ('Hello from the server, ' + firstName);
    }
}
```

---

Lightning Component

```
<aura:component controller="SimpleServerSideController">
    <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" default="world"/>
    <ui:button label="Call server" press="{!c.echo}"/>
</aura:component>
```

---

Client-side Controller

```
({
    "echo" : function(cmp) {
        // create a one-time use instance of the serverEcho action
        // in the server-side controller
        var action = cmp.get("c.serverEcho");
        action.setParams({ firstName : cmp.get("v.firstName") });

        // Create a callback that is executed after 
        // the server-side action returns
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            // This callback doesn’t reference cmp. If it did,
            // you should run an isValid() check
            //if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // Alert the user with the value returned 
                // from the server
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());

                // You would typically fire a event here to trigger 
                // client-side notification that the server-side 
                // action is complete
            }
            //else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
            //else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "ERROR") {
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });

        // optionally set storable, abortable, background flag here

        // A client-side action could cause multiple events, 
        // which could trigger other events and 
        // other server-side action calls.
        // $A.enqueueAction adds the server-side action to the queue.
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```